# How to create and inject multiple elements with Mootools?

Tags: mootools

I have 5 a elements that I need to inject with additional span , instead of creating new Element 5 times how can I do this only once ? I tried

```
var holders= $$('.holders');
holders.each(function (el){
var addspan = new Element('span', {
    'class': 'over'
});
    el.inject(addspan , 'top');
});
```

but it does not work 
any help is appreciated , thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Injection works the other way around; [it injects an element into another one](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3ainject). Try reversing `addspan` and `el`.

Another option would be to use the [`adopt`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3aadopt) function, which might be more intuitively meant to have an element adopt another one.

Comment: If you want to set the position use `grab` instead of `adopt`. It works the same way but only for one element at a time. `grab` is the counterpart of `inject`.

Comment: @Benn if it works, you should mark the replay as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Like akaIDIOT already mentioned, you have to swap `addspan` and `el` when using the `inject` method. To save a line of code, you can chain the `inject` method with the new element like this:

```
var holders= $$('.holders');
holders.each(function(el) {
    var addspan = new Element('span', {
        'class': 'over'
    }).inject(el, 'top');
});
```

Comment: You can shorten it even further by writing new Element("span.over").inject(el, 'top');